# Can we import our locally created lambda function to AWS console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have been working on AWS Lambda. For some reason, I had to create a Lambda function locally. I just want to know, can we import local lambda function to aws lambda console. If yes then please elaborate how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Assume you create the Lambda function using the Java run-time API (**com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler**) and you create a FAT JAR that contains all of the required dependencies. You can deploy the Lambda function (the JAR) using the AWS Management Console, as described in this AWS tutorial.

[Creating an AWS Lambda function that detects images with Personal Protective Equipment](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/usecases/creating_lambda_ppe)

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty easy:

1. Write your lambda function with a lambda_handler
2. Create a requirements.txt
3. Install all the requirements in the same folder
4. Package it(Zip file).
5. Go to AWS Lambda --> Create function --> Fill all details --> Create function.
6. Under code section: upload from --> .zip file ---> (select your file) --> upload--> save
7. Modify the handler according to your function name.